# Frame within a Frame in TKinter unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to place 2 frames inside a frame which in turn is placed on a TKinter window.  I expect the code below to produce 4 equal frames on a window and then place 2 equal frames within the first frame.  What I get is four equal frames with the top two frames each containing one frame.

I am calling the frame I wish to place the two smaller/equal frames into but I appear to be getting the window reference.  From what I have read I believe frames can be placed within frames.

```
from tkinter import *

class list_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self,the_window):
        super().__init__()
        self["height"]=50
        self["width"]=200
        self["relief"]=RAISED
        self["bd"]=8
        self["bg"]="red"

class little_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self,the_frame):
        super().__init__()
        self["height"]=20
        self["width"]=50
        self["relief"]=RAISED
        self["bd"]=8
        self["bg"]="black"

my_window = Tk()
my_window.geometry("400x300+0+0")

frame_a = list_frame(my_window)
frame_a.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame_b = list_frame(my_window)
frame_b.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame_c = list_frame(my_window)
frame_c.grid(row=1, column=0)
frame_d = list_frame(my_window)
frame_d.grid(row=1, column=1)

frame_e = little_frame(frame_a)
frame_e.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame_f = little_frame(frame_a)
frame_f.grid(row=0, column=1)

my_window.mainloop()
```

I am sure this is a stupid simple mistake but I don't see it and repeated sessions are not making it jump out at me.

Comment: In `little_frame`, you didn't pass on the `the_frame` parameter to the superclass, so those Frames were created as children of the root by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the parent through to the superclass `__init__`. Because of that, all of the frames are children of the root window.

You need to be doing this:

```
class list_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self,the_window):
        super().__init__(the_window)
        ...

class little_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self,the_frame):
        super().__init__(the_frame)
        ...
```

Since a frame doesn't care whether the containing widget is a window, a frame, or any other widget, it would probably be better to rename `the_window` and `the_frame` to `master` or `parent`

```
class list_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        ...

class little_frame (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.